# height attribute is not working as expected for html <object> tag

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and learning it from w3schools. I am looking at object tag and trying to display a pdf in a browser. I am unable to understand why the height attribute doesn't work in below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>try here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object data="redBus_Ticket_25718916.pdf" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%">sample</object> 

  </body>
</html>
```

I am expecting the entire page to be a PDF document. but what I see is,

[image]

Can some one tell me reason for such behavior ?

Interestingly when I remove the  definition, it works as expected. Don't know how they are related.Please help me in understanding the behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In CSS or wherever, also set heights for html and body,

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

I think the problem is that your content is small, so the document itself doesn't take much space, and hence 100% of document doesn't show in the entire page.

Without setting min height and height for html and body,

**[JSFIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/27/)**

After setting min-height and height for html, body,

**[JSFIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/26/)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. Can you provide more details on how setting min-height: 100% solved the problem ? how height: 100% and min-height: 100% are different in their usage specific to above scenario.

Comment: min-height as the name suggests would make the document's,and body's height to atleast 100%, i.e the page size. But if you set only height, still the problem would be what if content is so small, that it cannot cover the page, then min-height is required. If the problem is solved, you may mark the answer accepted.

Comment: well the content is not to small. Its a PDF file with 1 page of content. When I remove DOCTYPE definition, I could see the object loaded with expected height. Can you explain this behavior ?

Comment: DOCTYPE is to define use of HTML5, without any document type definition, it may behave unexpectedly, you say it is expected height, NO, it is not, expected height for me is what you get when you use DOCTYPE, you say content is 1 pdf page, no content is just the object tag, and for just one object tag, the height it takes looks right.

Comment: @OptimusPrime you were exactly rite it fixed my issue.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: There is only one problem - what if you have more than one page on the PDF? This works on single page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
 $('object').attr({'width':$( window ).width()})
    $('object').attr({'height':$( window ).height()});
</script>
```

```html
 <object data="index.html" type="text/html"><p>This is the fallback code!</p></object>
```